# deleting scrolls after running through data

Tags: elasticsearch

The host from where I receive large amount of data is telling med that I leave the scrolls without closing or deleting them.

I have been searching for a solution, but can't fin any. I use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder, but the documentation doesn't tell anything about closing the scrolls

I think that when the scrolls stop getting any hits I should teminate it, but I can't think of how.

```
$result = $client->scroll([
           'body' => [
               'scroll_id' =>  $result['_scroll_id'],
               'scroll'    => '5m'
           ]
        ]);
```